# JSON file empty when i open it with app json viewer

Tags: java, android, json

With my code, when I open a `JSON file` with an app for smartphone `JSON VIEWER`, the file is empty. I do not see the content.

Why?

Now, I'll show you my code how I save the file in `json`

Thanks in advance everybody!

```
public String showResult(View v) throws IOException {
String  result = "";

        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()){
                json.put("name",p.getName());
                json.put("distance",p.getDistance());
                json.put("quantity",p.getQuantità());

            }
        }
         result=json.toString();

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText/";

        //FileWriter file=null;

    /*  try {
            file = new FileWriter(path+"filename5.json");
            file.write(result);


        }catch(IOException ie){}
        finally{


            file.flush();
            file.close();
        }*/
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path+"filename31.json");
            file.write(result);
            file.close();
            System.out.println("Successfully wrote Json result to file.");
        /*catch(IOException r){

        }*/
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;

    }
```

JsonObject class:

```
private static class JsonObject {
        public void put(String name, String name1) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you are trying to store in Json file?

Comment: the name of the checkbox selected

Answer (score 0):

You never closed the `FileWriter`. Always close `Reader` and `Writer` objects.

```
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(path+"filename31.json");
file.write(result);
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gson.jar` 
Instead of custom `JsonObject` use `com.google.gson.JsonObject` which will generate perfect `JSON` string.

```
 JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("name", "s");
        json.addProperty("distance", "2");
        json.addProperty("quantity", "2");

        result = json.toString();
```

String will be:

> {"name":"s","distance":"2","quantity":"2"}

Comment: i imported gson.jar and now how i must write JsonObject?

Comment: import com.google.gson.JsonObject; instead of you own JsonObject.